# Setting cell with a formula

Tags: formatting, libreoffice-calc

In LibreCalc I am trying to set a field to a color depending on what number is entered in the field. The column **C** needs to be the color red if it is 25% or less of Column **B**.

Column **C** also needs to be the color green when it is above 75% and the color orange when it is between 25% and 75%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Format`, choose `Conditional Formatting` --> `Condition`.  You will see a dialog box where you can impose the `Condition` with the setting `Formula is` as follows; enter the formula:

```
(C1 / B1) <= .25
```

Then, add a new style with the desired background color, red.  Say `ok` and then `add` another condition, this time with the second contingency:

```
(C1 / B1) > .25 and  (C1 / B1) <= .75
```

Repeat adding style, this time do the background for the style orange.  Then add a third condition for green, with the right formula and another style.

After you are done, copy the contents of the cell to each other cell desired to be formatted in this way.  You will be able to review all of the conditional formatting from the `Manage` option of the conditional formatting menu.  Calc automatically alters the cell formulas to shift the cell references to the same extent as copying.

For reference, see [LO page about conditional formatting](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting).

Comment: I propose in the above answer "copy the contents of the cell" should read "copy the formating of the cell" (by way of copy and paste special)